# EXcel- extract specific value from cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

cell A1: `/abcd/efgh/ijklhh/xxxxx_yyyyyy/`

cell A2 I want to print in A2 cell: `xxxxx_yyyyyy` only

note : last word `xxxxx_yyyyyy` name can differ in cell to cell.

Comment: I have found http://stackoverflow.com/a/15915250/335583 to be very helpful for that matter as Excel does not have a working explode() on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mimic a split-type function by substituting the deliminating character(s) for a large number of spaces and use `MID` to pick out the section you want.

[image: Split and Trim on SUBSTITUTE]

The formula in A2 is,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ",99)), 199))
```

By replacing the slashes with a large number of spaces, you make it possible to use `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `MID` to peel out the section that you are looking for. The `TRIM` function removed the extraneous spaces bracketing what you've parsed.

The other two formulas in the sample image are,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ",99)), 299, 99))
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ",99)), 199))
```