# Sorting out disorganized data in Excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet here with a bucket load of data on in but it's all compressed into one cell for each "entity" (it's customer test data).
I have had a look at other answered questions but none of them have solved my problem. 
This is an example of the data that I have (There's a lot):

```
{"Url":"https://portal.freemarketfx.com/User/RegisterIndividual","Method":"POST","Form":"{\"__RequestVerificationToken\":\"yBPOicSq9wwIFC4IgI_CDB8RSrJonaRM4ztEo0_1pygdrrIMVP12ivGDF7-bvoIGXIc1vsTSQjB_UKAA3t32AcW9ULbuKdHSFD8TQRPnW9jRj5CBj1Pe9tund8mPUG8Eqjutr-EQ3tMnVsSdrXDkfw2\",\"PostbackData\":\"{}\",\"Title\":\"Mr\",\"FirstName\":\"Sebastien\",\"YourDateofBirth\":\"31/01/1983\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"MiddleName\":\"Pascal Emmanuel\",\"IDNumberType\":\"Passport\",\"IDNumber\":\"11CX03708\",\"Surname\":\"Py\",\"AddressList.Index\":\"0\",\"AddressList[0].SinceYear\":\"2015\",\"AddressList[0].SinceMonth\":\"3\",\"AddressList[0].SinceDay\":\"25\",\"AddressList[0].UntilYear\":\"2017\",\"AddressList[0].UntilMonth\":\"3\",\"AddressList[0].UntilDay\":\"25\",\"AddressList[0].HouseNumber\":\"05 06\",\"AddressList[0].HouseName\":\"\",\"AddressList[0].FlatNumber\":\"\",\"AddressList[0].Street\":\"29 Adam Road\",\"AddressList[0].CityTown\":\"Singapore\",\"AddressList[0].Postcode\":\"289901\",\"AddressList[0].County\":\"\",\"AddressList[0].District\":\"\",\"AddressList[0].Country\":\"SG\",\"ChannelList.Index\":\"0,1\",\"ChannelList[0].ChannelType\":\"Email\",\"ChannelList[0].Address\":\"sebastienpy@gmail.com\",\"ChannelList[0].TelephoneConnectionType\":\"Cellular\",\"ChannelList[0].TelephonePurpose\":\"Personal\",\"ChannelList[0].CountryCallingCode\":\"\",\"ChannelList[0].TelephoneNumber\":\"\",\"ChannelList[1].ChannelType\":\"Telephone\",\"ChannelList[1].Address\":\"\",\"ChannelList[1].TelephoneConnectionType\":\"Cellular\",\"ChannelList[1].TelephonePurpose\":\"Personal\",\"ChannelList[1].CountryCallingCode\":\"65\",\"ChannelList[1].TelephoneNumber\":\"87275217\",\"PartyIdentificationType\":\"BicIbanAccountNumber\",\"BankBranchCode\":\"\",\"Bic\":\"HSBCSGSG143\",\"AccountNumber\":\"583474496\",\"AccountSetupDate\":\"\",\"ReasonForExchange\":\"TransferToOwnAccount\",\"ReasonForExchangeOther\":\"\",\"MaxPaymentAmount\":\"0\",\"MaxPaymentAmountCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"CurrenciesRequired\":\"EUR,USD,SGD\",\"FrequencyOfTransfer\":\"Annual\",\"AnnualTransactionsValue\":\"0\",\"AnnualTransactionsValueCurrency\":\"GBP\",\"Destinations\":\"FR\",\"Referrer\":\"\",\"AcceptTerms\":\"true,false\"}","Referrer":"https://portal.freemarketfx.com/User/RegisterIndividual","User Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36","entityId":"1","SendEmailRegistration":"{\"Email\":\"registrations@freemarketfx.com\",\"Data\":{\"FirstName\":\"Sebastien Py\",\"Subject\":\"Registration complete\"}}","ActiveAccount":""}
```

My question is is there any way to sort all this out into a cell for each piece of data? Bear in mind that there are hundreds of other cells just like this one, so I don't want to have to go through every single one manually.
A large portion of this data looks very much like a Python dictionary, and i was going to write a piece of code to exploit this but I don't know if there is a faster in-built function in excel? 
P.S since the data varies from one customer to another, the data will not be the same length (just in case you want to use =MID, =RIGHT, or =LEFT functions)

Comment: Why would you put this sort of data in Excel in the first place?

Comment: For what it's worth, you are probably looking at JSON.

Comment: tripleee, I just received it like this, trust me it would not have been my first choice...

Comment: Export to a text file and take it from there.  Maybe tell the person who sent you this about text files.

Comment: actually tripleee i did not realise it was json (or know what json is for that matter) - i've managed to convert it to normal text by saving the details in notepad as a json file and then using a converter. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "," is acting as a primary delimiter between sets of data, and ":" as a secondary one. i.e. `"Url":"https://portal.freemarketfx.com/User/RegisterIndividual","Method":"POST",...` - a "," splits different types of data (url, method etc.) and a colon ":" splits values from data types (eg. the value for Url is https://portal...)

So what would be nice is to take the raw entity data, split into data types by separating the raw data at each comma, then split the data values from their respective headings. There are several ways of doing this in Excel. If you don't mind VBA, take a look at this; [Excel "UnCONCATENATE"/explode in function / Convert cell into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914761/excel-unconcatenate-explode-in-function-convert-cell-into-array)

If you'd rather use a formula, then the basic idea would be in `B1`; `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(",",A1))` whatever comes before the "," (where `A1` holds your raw data)
Then in `A2`; `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"",1)` to chop the left hand side of the raw data off, and then just drag Columns A and B down until B contains every data type

Finally, in C1 and D2 have

`=LEFT(B1,SEARCH(":",B1))` and `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,C1,"",1)` respectively, to chop the data type into a heading and a value

Drag down and columns C&D will have all your raw data split up. It's a similar story for the VBA approach, and for both, you might have to clean up the results a bit with `TRIM` and `SUBSTITUTE` to remove trash.

Hope that's clear!